# When is $n! \geq m!$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, inequality

I was wondering on proving under whose conditions is $n! \geq m!$, so I've started by writing
$$n! \geq m! \Leftrightarrow n(n-1)\cdot...\cdot3\cdot2\cdot1 \geq m(m-1)\cdot3\cdot2\cdot1$$
So if I suppose $n \geq m$ we have that the inequality can be written as
$$n! \geq m! \Leftrightarrow n(n-1)\cdot...\cdot(n-m)\cdot...\cdot m(m-1)\cdot...\cdot3\cdot2\cdot1 \geq m(m-1)\cdot3\cdot2\cdot1$$
Since $k!$ is defined as the product of $k$ for all the natural number lesser to $k$, we have that $m(m-1)\cdot...\cdot 3 \cdot2\cdot1 \geq 0$ and so we can divide both sides for it arriving to
$$n(n-1)\cdot...\cdot(n-m)\cdot...\cdot (n-m+1) \geq 0$$
And this inequality is always true because we have supposed $n\geq m$ and for the factorial definition I've said before; so can I conclude that if $n \geq m$ then $n! \geq m!$?

Is this proof correct or it has flaws? It seems easy, indeed it seems very intuitive that if a non negative number is greater than other so is its factorial. Thanks.

Comment: The proof seems correct (up to the typo where 0 should be 1). Although, I don't think this needs a proof. Its clear that $n!$ increases when $n$ increases since you are multiplying more numbers ($\geq 1$).

Comment: It's fine.  But note that $(n+1)!=(n+1)n!>n!$.  So $n!$ is strictly increasing.

Comment: @MarkViola I was wondering about that. As 0!=1!, is n! strictly increasing? I am new to this topic so I was curious.

Comment: It's strictly increasing on $n \ge 1$ as $n\ge 1\implies (n+1)! > n!$.  It does not increase from $0!$ to $1!$.

Comment: @fleablood Even more precisely $\Gamma(1+x)$ increases for values of $x\approx 0.46$.

Comment: @JulianMejia: Yes there is a typo, is $1$ on the RHS of the inequality! Thanks for pointing it out.
And thanks to all the others for the interesting comments!